# OSM basemap under XYZ tiles and geojson file both in WGS84 not matching

Tags: qgis-3, openstreetmap, xyz-tiles

I use QGIS 3.14. I would like to add a basemap under my other layers (parcel limits in a city near Paris). I clicked on "OpenStreetMap" under XYZ tiles in the left panel and a map of the world is displayed, except that my city parcels are now in the middle of the gulf of Guinea near Africa instead of being near Paris. Seems like a CRS issue, except that both OpenStreetMap and my files (from French open data agency Etalab) seem to be in WGS84.

Any idea as to why this is like this?

Comment: And now I downloaded the whole "département" as a shapefile and it lands in the Netherlands instead of near Paris (it is 77, Seine-et-Marne)...

Comment: it's weird because I have another file with geopackage and csv files and there OSM works well.

Comment: OpenStreetmap layer is using EPSG 3857.

Comment: Are you sure that XYZ tiles are rendered in `EPSG:4326` (WGS84)?

OSM tiles are often rendered in `EPSG:3857` (Web Mercator).

Comment: Here it says EPSG:4326 (WGS84), I changed to 3857 but my data is still in the middle of the gulf of Guinea. Does it need to be the same CRS for both or not? Thank you!

Comment: No. OpenStreetMap tiles are always using EPSG:3857. Then if your overlay layer, cadastre here is a GeoJSON, it should be EPSG 4326 as by default GeoJSON does not support other CRS in the specification

Comment: Thank you in the end I created a new project and by adding the OSM tiles first it worked perfectly this time. Not sure why, maybe it is because the first time i added the tiles after adding the rest of the layers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made a demo by adding first OpenStreetMap tiles (EPSG:3857) and then shapefile within file cadastre-77-parcelles-shp.zip from https://cadastre.data.gouv.fr/data/etalab-cadastre/2020-10-01/shp/departements/77/ that use EPSG:2154.

If you use the GeoJSON version e.g https://cadastre.data.gouv.fr/data/etalab-cadastre/2020-10-01/geojson/departements/77/ your cadastre layer will be EPSG:4326 (WGS84)

As you can see they overlay correctly by default. No need to touch to any EPSG declaration

If you are always stuck, tell us how did you proceed exactly as I can't reproduce your issue by editing your answer and providing us more details.

[image]

Comment: Now it works! I created a new project and first clicked on OpenStreetMap tiles and then voilà ! I think that the first time I added the basemap after adding the other data and for some reason it messed up the result. Thank you very much!